# Jump from resolved[dupe] to closed

Tags: jira

We have a fairly standard jira workflow

open -> in progress -> resolved -> ready for testing -> tested -> closed

and the various loops associated with reopen, etc.

But we have a few resolutions where that does not make sense:

- duplicate
- can't reproduce
- won't fix

These resolutions are generally set by developers.  When QA and/or management confirms the resolution, we would like to go straight to closed, since there is no ready for testing/tested phase.

Is it possible to do that in jira?  If so, how so...

Note that we are not satisfied with leaving the issue simply 'resolved' because the agile board lists all issues that are not closed (and probably rightly so).

Answer (score 0):

JIRA works best when the resolution is only set when moving into a final status such as Closed. You should be able to add transitions to the workflow from any status to Closed. The agile board can be configured to show or hide issues with the Quick Filters.

Comment: The concern is that folks will click the closed button before they should for other resolved states.  We don't want resolved[fixed] going directly to closed without passing through the testing phases.